# Rails: how to split string after a specific character

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a column `name` in database which holds strings like `CVM&#8482;` what I want to do is to split it so everything after ampersand goes into a different column and everything before the string stays where it was. The final result should put `&#8482;` into a column called `abbr` and save `CVM` into `name` column.

Answer (score 1):

Create a rake task file

```
lib/tasks/split_name.rake
```

Then paste in the following, and change "TableName" to your actual table name.

```
task :split_name => :environment do
    TableName.all.each do |r|
        a = r.name.split("&") #assuming exact same string format, and not null
        r.update_attribute(:name, a[0])
        r.update_attribute(:abbr, '&' + a[1])
    end
end
```

Then run it as such

```
rake split_name
```

Comment: instead of 2 queries to database, should be one, 
    r.name = a[0]; r.abbr = ... r.save

Answer (score 0):

Must this be done Rails level? You can also do this with just Postgres with `split_part` function. I assume you're working with `users` table:

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN abbr VARCHAR;

UPDATE users 
  SET name = SPLIT_PART(name, '&#8482;', 1),
      abbr = '&#8482;' || SPLIT_PART(name, '&#8482;', 2);
```

You can also bake these queries into a Rake task if needed.

Update: Opps I assumed you were using Postgres. But other languages should have similar method that you can use.